# Bulk entry status change

Tags: channel-entries, status, bulk

Is there a way to change the status of a number of entries at one time?

I know you can select a number of checkboxes and then edit all, but thats still time consuming if you have pages of entries. (In my case, many thousands)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This query should work:

```
UPDATE exp_channel_titles t 
SET t.status = 'pending' 
WHERE t.status = 'open'
AND t.channel_id = 'x'
```

Change 'x' to your channel id.

Comment: It also works without the t.

Comment: In my SQL editor, the code coloring on 'status' was showing it as a reserved word, so I wanted to be more specific.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a specific list of entry_ids you want to change, you can run a query like this with your entry_ids separated by commas:

```
  UPDATE exp_channel_titles t 
    SET t.status = 'pending' 
    WHERE t.status = 'open'
    AND t.entry_id in (1,2,3,4)
```