# Mass-change entries from one status to another

Tags: ee3, status, sql, entry-date, bulk

We cannot bulk-edit entries via the CP, and I need to make a change in my workflow. In one channel, I need to mass-change all entries whose current status is OPEN to CREATED, if the entry-date is before a certain date.

I'm fairly sure that this is possible with SQL (Developer Tools > SQL Manager > Query Form), but...I don't know SQL. I think this question covers SOME of it (how to change entry statuses), but not all of it (only in a certain channel, only before a certain entry date): [Bulk entry status change](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/bulk-entry-status-change)

Help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SQL is the best option to bulk update the entries. But you must need to be careful as wrong execution can stress you up!

You can use below query:

```
UPDATE exp_channel_titles 
SET status = 'created' 
WHERE status = 'open' 
AND channel_id = '1' 
AND entry_date <= '1262332799'
```

Replace the date value with UNIX timestamps of the date and channel_id you want use.

Comment: Thanks! I'll make a backup of the database before running this query...ju-u-ust in case :) (A new version of EE just came out, so I also have to upgrade. I'll do that after I run this query.) Thanks again for the exact syntax!

Comment: EE 3 still doesn't allow bulk updates from the CP like EE2 did. I believe it's on the feature request list to be added back in. Hopefully EL will accommodate us users.

Comment: Yes @Jeremy - that's true. (At least it is up through EE3.5.2, I haven't upgraded to 3.5.3 yet.) I've posted in threads in the official forums that I'd like the more granular search, AND the bulk edit. Both of those were nice features to have in the CP...don't know why they removed them!